# OAuth 2 Client Id Duplicate Issue

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, sha1, google-contacts-api

I have created one oauth 2.0 credential for my live app with debugging key and it is working fine. Then I have created another oauth 2.0 credential with signed key but my signed application not working properly with google authentication. Then I have delete the second oauth credential(the one with signed key) and try to update the signed key in the first credential but it shows the duplicate fingerprint error. What can I do? I cant change my package name or signed key since the application already in live store. Can I recover that deleted oauth Client Id? or can I update the an existing credential with my signed key? Please help.

Comment: I think the steps provided in the post by the Google play support team could help you go through. They have provided the checklist to guide you on how to update your app in the Google plat Store. See [this post from the support team](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en).